# NetSuite: How to set an eventhandler for cancel/voided vendor bills

Tags: javascript, netsuite

How can I listen to the cancel/voided vendor bill event?

I have this code to listen to the "delete" event:

```js
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.1
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(["N/record", "N/https", "N/file", "./ent_sync_funciones"], (...args) => {


  const afterSubmit = (context) => {
    //I know these events, but in the netsuite doc has so many other events
    //context.UserEventType.CREATE
    //context.UserEventType.EDIT
    //context.UserEventType.DELETE
    if(context.UserEventType.DELETE){
      ....
    }
  };
  return {
    afterSubmit,
  };
});
```

but this does not work for me, because the users don't go to delete that.